# is JQuery the only way to create a popup box

Tags: jquery

this is just a simple question, a yes or no answer am I am looking for. there is no need to mark down this question, just need to know basis

Comment: No, its not the only way....

Comment: jQuery is nothing but javascript. So, with a combination of html, css and javascript , you can create anything you want. Whether you use jQuery or not.

Comment: It would have taken you less time to Google this than it did to write the question

Comment: `alert("this is in a 'popup' box")` - that's not jquery.

Answer (score 0):

We do appreciate if you could take your time in research before writing such questions in SO coz a simple Google search could solve your query

Coming back to question,

There are many ways to create a popup in UI, JQuery is one of the option.

Coming to the choice of Languages, It mainly depends on the designers choice which language to use. No one is restricted to express their creativity.

Commonly used languages to achieve popups the are Jquery, JS, CSS.

I wrote two pens for you to explain the same, 
CSS :

```
`https://codepen.io/mightyteja/pen/ywNjQw`
```

Javascript :

```
`https://codepen.io/mightyteja/pen/zbGaxv`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you mean a pop up as I imagine, the answer is no, b'z we can make it using many ways,  css3, pure javascript, ... for example.